# SMO Assemblies in .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I am using .net framework 4.0 and working on Web deployment Setup, I have referenced the SMO Assemblies of sql server 2008, and When I Call ExecuteNonQuery Function in my setup using Smo Assemblies it gives me this error "Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information." but sometimes it works correctly in my code but some time it gives this error,

I have using the same class, same method sometimes its run correctly and some time it gives this error, I am completely fade up with this error, I couldn't find any reason for that and I also want to know is SMO assemblies are available in .Net framework v4.0?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/533f7044-1109-4b7a-a697-2621f23017d6

This is a known issue. SMO's usage against .Net 4.0 hasnt been signed off or announced by microsoft.

There is an unsupported option to get this working (add this to your app.config):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The solution proposed by jimasp does not work. I am amazed why there is no exact approach yet to tackle with this problem. Searched more than two dozen links but no resolve. Using SqlClient I have problem with "GO" statements so can't use that approach either. Note: I have created a Web Steup installer and from that I call a Windows Form project for executing these T-Sql script related code using SMO.

Comment: I tried this and it does work for me using Windows Forms.  My concern is I don't know what side-effects useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" might have going forward.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using "SMO assemblies" to call ExecuteNonQuery?

Why not just reference and use ADO.NET? See [`System.Data.SqlClient.ExecuteNonQuery(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

Comment: This is probably not relevant to this particular OP, but you need the SMO libraries when you want to call [ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) which gives you the ability to run a sql script with the *GO* keyword in it.

Comment: I tried ADO (as well as the approach used in the answer below) and got it to work.  I may stick with it as I am concerned about side-effects of useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true".

Comment: Im running my code from unit tests so in the I went for this option,
so none of my SQL scripts can have GO statements.

workaround: you could scan your SQL scripts for GO and split into smaller scripts.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer for using SMO in .NET v4 right now seems to be here in the workaround:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/643811/net-4-0-compatible-smo

Answer (score 1):

I myself came across this issue and adding the aforementioned tag (see @jimasp comment) did not seem to work, however, I had added it to the app.config for the project that the code was located in, however, it was being used as part of a console application. When I added it to the console's app.config it ran without any issues. I had been adding it to the wrong app.config.