# c# Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without

Tags: c#, sql-server

i have little error here

```
server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

from this code :

```
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
namespace trycollation
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=True";
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\dimitar.grudev\AppData\Local\Temp\RDBS\Satage1\TRZPro_17083118563804_step1.sql");
            string script = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
            server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to add application configuration file with this code inside:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

but still have same error. Where I wrong?

Error :

> Additional information: Mixed mode assembly is built against version
>   'v2.0.50727' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime
>   without additional configuration information.

This not help me : [SMO Assemblies in .Net Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534682/smo-assemblies-in-net-framework-4-0)

Comment: not sure whether need `conn.open()`

Comment: still doesn't work...

Comment: I guess so, just curious whether that may help, but it seems that is certain configuration issue, no clue of that :(

Comment: Yep and I search for help

Comment: System.IO.FileLoadException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146232799
 Is this enought?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMO Assemblies in .Net Framework 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534682/smo-assemblies-in-net-framework-4-0)

Comment: Nope, not duplicate.

Comment: You added that configuration block to the configuration file of the **startup** project, right?  The config block looks correct to me, it *should* be working if it was placed in the correct location.

Comment: Where is the correct location for config?